# How to read and Write to a local sqlite database with Chrome Packaged apps?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome

I am trying to write to a database from Chrome Packaged app. Is this even possible with the filesystem API? If it is possible how can I implement it and if it isn't possible what alternatives do I have? I want to avoid a server altogether I want this app to run locally at all times and I need the persistent storage. I was using TideSDK previously apparently it is not under active development.